# python list insert function allows me to enter index beyond the allowable range. why?

Tags: python

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_list.insert(-5, 99)
```

Expected: Index out of range
Instead: 99 inserted at `my_list[0]`

```
print(my_list) # output: [99, 1, 2, 3]
del my_list[0]
my_list.insert(6, 99)
```

Expected: Index out of range
Instead: 99 inserted at `my_list[3]`

```
print(my_list) # output: [1, 2, 3, 99]
```

Comment: Why?  What do you believe is setting a range of allowed values? Why is the current behaviour an issue? Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `.insert` places an item before the given index.

Comment: I dont really understand your question. The answe to "why" this is allowed is "because whoever designed this API decided to make it work that way"

Answer (score 0):

**Why:** This is how the `insert()` method is designed.

To briefly explain the steps-

`my_list.insert(-5, 99)` Inserts 99 at index -5, which is out of range, so it's placed at the **beginning of the list**. that's why 99 is inserted at `my_list[0]` -> `output: [99, 1, 2, 3]`

`del my_list[0]` Deletes the first element. So `output: [1, 2, 3]`

`my_list.insert(6, 99)` Inserts 99 at index 6, which is out of range, so it's placed at the **end of the list**. that's why, 99 is inserted at `my_list[3]` -> `output: [1, 2, 3, 99]`